Deserializing using JSON.NET
I am new to JSON and am trying to understand how to use JSON.NET to deserialize the following JSON response.
{
  "student 1": {
    "first_name": "Peter",
    "last_name": "Wilks",
    "gender": "Male",
    "subjects": {
      "226630": "Math",
      "260213": "Art",
      "226629": "Sport"
    },
    "home_group": ""
  },
  "student 2": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smth",
    "gender": "Male",
    "subjects": {     
      "226626": "Physics",
      "226628": "Chemistry"     
    },
    "home_group": ""
  },
  "teacher 1": {
    "first_name": "Sally",
    "last_name": "Manning",
    "gender": "Female",
    "subjects": {
    },
    "home_group": ""
  },
  "student 3": {
    "first_name": "Joan",
    "last_name": "Bradley",
    "gender": "Female",
    "subjects": {
      "226632": "Geography",
      "260213": "Art",
      "226629": "Sport"
    },
    "home_group": ""
  }
}

I am able to deserialize into separate variables: student 1; student 2; student 3; teacher 1.
What I would like to be able to do is deserialize into a single List
public class MyClass
{
    public List<Person> persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Subject[] subjects { get; set; }
    public string homegroup { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

Where persons.id store the values: student 1; student 2; student 3; teacher 1

Your root object corresponds to a Dictionary<string, Person> where the dictionary key corresponds to the id.  So deserialize as JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Person>>(jsonString).  You can later set the id if necessary, or leave it as a dictionary and remove the id.  See Serialize a Dictionary and also Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name, which looks to be a duplicate.  Agree?

Awesome, thanks :)
